# Writing Queries in sqlite with vb.net & uwp

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, uwp

I have searched most of SO, and spent countless hours googling, so I'm going to post in the hopes that someone can help or just tell me it can't be done!

I am trying to make my vb.net uwp application be able to query a local sqlite database with a test query, but I am at a complete loss trying to find an example or any sort of documentation that isn't in c# without a clear parallel to how to translate to vb.net.

I have a base test class that can successfully connect with my database file, but I can't find anywhere how to do a query - all the resources online just link me to either vb.net without uwp or c# with uwp! I'll paste my code, but links to any resources or any advice would be so so helpful :)

```
Public Class dtbTest
Private conn As SQLiteConnection
Private sqcommand As SQLiteCommand
Private query As String = "SELECT * FROM userdetails"
Private cnn As SQLiteConnection
Private DBConnection As String = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.s3db")
Private tableInfo As List(Of SQLiteConnection.ColumnInfo)

Public Sub New()
    Try

        conn = New SQLiteConnection(DBConnection)
        conn.BeginTransaction()
        tableInfo = conn.GetTableInfo("userdetails")
        sqcommand.CommandText = query
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case people are interested, I got it working by trying the new Microsoft.Data.SQL package, so would recommend checking that if anyone is having similar problems!

Comment: *"I don't have an answer to the original problem, so I exchanged the problem for something else"* - That's not the type of answer that SO expects.

Comment: If this solution manages to write a query to the same database, does it matter if it's a hack?

Comment: Since you were asking, what standards answers should meet at SO, have a look at [answer]. Reading [ask] is recommended as well.